# undefined method for nil class when rendering partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, partial

I'm trying to run this code and it returns me

> > undefined method `image' for nil:NilClass

But the syntax and the code seems to be good.

index :

```
 - @recipes.each_slice(4) do |recipes|
  .row
    - recipes.each do |recipe|
      .col-md-3
         %h4.modal-title= recipe.title
         .modal-body
            = render :partial =>'show', :locals => {:recipe => @recipe}
```

_show:

```
.main_content
  #recipe_top.row
    .col-md-4
      = image_tag @recipe.image.url(:medium), class:"recipe_image"
```

Comment: The only place you're calling `image` is in `_show`, so we know that the problem is `@recipe` is `nil`. Please edit your question to include the controller code where you set `@recipe`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
= render :partial =>'show', :locals => { :recipe => recipe }
```

Since you don't have a instance variable `@recipe`, but a local variable `recipe` defined in the line `recipes.each do |recipe|`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,
Just replace your instance variable @recipe when passing in locale because you already done eaching on it and gets local variable recipe so pass that in your locale and then call like this in your show page.

```
 recipe.image.url(:medium)
```

Answer (score 1):

**You have wrong implication in code:**

instead of `:recipe => @recipe`
use `:recipe => recipe` and then in show partial just use `recipe` instead of `@recipe`

**Or**

in index define `@recipe = recipe` and use `@recipe` in show.